# Getting the first when using simple html dom PHP

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm using http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm to select certain parts of an external page.

I've successfully been able to grab the following 
`$result = $html->find('#sidebar-bgbtm .data', 0)->outertext;`

But the problem is, there are two `.data` elements inside `#sidebar-bgbtm`

How would I be able to just select the first element?

Comment: You're already getting it !  `$html->find('#sidebar-bgbtm .data')` returns an array of all found elements, and `$html->find('#sidebar-bgbtm .data', $index)` will return only the element specified by `$index` which is in your case `0` to get the 1st element...

Answer (score 1):

I think this link [Manual API](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm) can help you

element $e->first_child ()